# Index exceeds matrix dimensions in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying out some matlab code straight from the matlab documentation, but when I paste in into a clean matlab file and run it am getting 'Index exceeds matrix dimensions.'
the code is to get a user input:

```
reply = input('Do you want more? Y/N [Y]: ', 's');
if isempty(reply)
    reply = 'Y';
end
```

Comment: That code should work fine.  Are you sure that's the *exact* code you're running?

Comment: yep! copy and pasted it!

Comment: I reloaded matlab and it worked, i can only assume it was another variable I had in my work space was causing the error. Thanks for the comment, it hinted me to restart it.

Comment: In the future, you can use 'clear all' to clear all current variables. That way, you don't have to restart Matlab. You can also do 'clear variablename' to clear individual variables.

Comment: @cubeearth Can you please post your comment as an answer and accept it? Cheers

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs if a vector in the workspace is named "input", which causes MATLAB to try and find a subvector of "input" as opposed to calling the input command...